# Posting links into facebook groups using Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How we can post links into Facebook groups using Graph API in PHP/Javascript. I have followed the below documentation.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed

Syntax:

```
FB.api(
    "/{group-id}/feed",
    "POST",
    {
        "message": "This is a test message"
    },
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
   }
```

);

My Code:

```
FB.api(
    "/https://www.facebook.com/groups/990024677728712/feed",
    "POST",
    {
    "message": "The India national football team is governed by the All India Football Federation (AIFF). Since 1948, the AIFF has been affiliated with FIFA, the international governing body for football. In 1954, the AIFF became one of the founding members of the Asian Football Confederation (AFC). The team was automatically advanced to play in the 1950 FIFA World Cup (all the other Asian teams withdrew), but they did not go to the tournament in Brazil due to the cost of travels and certain financial crisis.[5] They won gold medals at two Asian Games and one silver at the Asian Cup.",
    "link": "https://www.the-aiff.com/"
    },
    function(response){
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
   }
);
```

It is not posting into facebook. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the url in the FB.api call. It starts with a slash (`/`). Also, I think you only should pass `/990024677728712/feed` instead of the entire url.

Comment: if i am doing like this, after posting getting error like this "The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action". I am the admin of the group also.

Answer (score 0):

The call needs to be to

```
FB.api(
    "/990024677728712/feed",
    "POST",
    ...
);
```

as outlined in the docs at

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/group/feed

It's also made clear in the docs that you need both `user_managed_groups` and `publish_actions` permissions if you want to post to the group's feed.

Comment: How can i get those permissions? Can you please tell me?

Comment: How about RTM: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/web StackOverflow is NOT a coding service

Comment: I have to get those permissions while logging in right? I can able to post using above method if i am not admin of the group also?

Comment: *...a user access token with publish_actions and user_managed_groups permission is required for someone able to post to the group*

Comment: <fb:login-button scope="public_profile,email,user_groups,publish_actions,user_managed_groups" onlogin="checkLoginState();"></fb:login-button>
I have added those permissions but if i am checking "/me/permissions" it only returns email and public_profile. Like this
{"data":[{"permission":"email","status":"granted"},{"permission":"public_profile","status":"granted"}]}

Comment: You need to try this with an app's admin/developer/tester user.